# What class design will be change in case of promotion of roles in employee class hierarchy

Tags: c++, class, oop, object, design-patterns

I am building a simple object-oriented inheritance class for the employee management system, but I found one issue if some employee gets promotions then how we can handle such scenario.

This code represents the employee class hierarchy using inheritance relation.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
/* This is Employee Class */
class Employee
{
private:
    string empname;
    int empid;
    float salary;
public:
    int getSalary();
};
/* This is Manager Class  Derived from Employee */
class Manager: public Employee
{
public:
    int getSalary(); // This will return salary of manager
};
/* This is Clerk Class  Derived from Employee */
class Clerk: public Employee
{
public:
    int getSalary(); // This will return salary of clerk
};
/* This is Accountant Class Derived from Employee */
class Accountant : public Employee
{
public:
    int getSalary(); // This will return salary of Accountant
};
/* This is Accountant Class Derived from Employee */
class Developer: public Employee
{
public:
    int getSalary(); // This will return salary of Developer
};
```

Now if some employee gets a promotion or demotion, how can I handle this situation?

Suppose someday Developer becomes Manager. How will I be able to apply those changes with C++ classes?

Comment: *"I found one issue"* What kind of an issue? An "issue" can mean many things.

Comment: You supposedly have a container with (pointers to) `Employee` objects? Then one possible solution could be to replace a pointer with a pointer to the new "promoted" objects and use copy-construction to copy all the details needed. As in `all_employees[some_developer_index] = new Manager(*all_employees[some_developer_index])` (note that I simplified the example, as it will currently leak memory).

Answer (score 0):

Since objects can't change type, all you can do is murder the old employee, then resurrect a copy of him/her/it/them with their new role. Whether their "soul" can be retained through this process is up to you to decide.

Your model wouldn't be employed (no pun intended) in real programs. The "rank" or pay grade of an employee would be a property of an employee, not their type. There are so many other properties of an employee and (as you've discovered) the values of these properties can change, so it makes no sense to bake them into the employee's identity.

Not everything has to be "object-oriented".

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for **State** design pattern.

The role of the employee is *a state*. As already mentioned by others there is no sense in killing employees just because they change role. Thus the role shouldn't define the employee. It should only be an attribute.

Suppose you have the following hierarchy of roles:

```
class Role { ... };

class Developer: public Role { ... };

class Manager: public Role { ... };
```

Then:

```
class Employee {
    Role role;
...
};
```